# How to get the last update date of kernel in AIX & Solaris

Tags: kernel, solaris, aix

I want to get the last update date of kernel in AIX & Solaris.

For Linux, the command is:

```
rpm -qa --last | grep kernel-`uname -r` | sed 's/^k.*\s\s//'
```

For this command I'm getting the output:

```
Wed 29 Nov 2017 03:26:48 PM EST
```

I need same replacement for AIX & Solaris as well.

I'm trying to execute this command for AIX, but it's not sophisticated proper output what I need:

```
lslpp -ha bos.adt.base | grep COMPLETE | sed 's/^k.*\s\s//'
Return Code: 0,                   6.1.1.0   COMMIT       COMPLETE     09/16/14     13:49:31    
                  6.1.1.0   APPLY        COMPLETE     09/16/14     13:49:31    
                 6.1.8.16   COMMIT       COMPLETE     09/16/14     13:59:18    
                 6.1.8.16   APPLY        COMPLETE     09/16/14     13:55:32    
                 6.1.9.30   COMMIT       COMPLETE     07/02/15     16:36:49    
                 6.1.9.30   APPLY        COMPLETE     07/02/15     16:33:22    
                 6.1.9.45   COMMIT       COMPLETE     09/04/15     15:45:19    
                 6.1.9.45   APPLY        COMPLETE     09/04/15     15:45:09    
                6.1.9.101   APPLY        COMPLETE     09/14/17     16:44:44    
                  6.1.1.0   COMMIT       COMPLETE     09/16/14     13:49:36    
                  6.1.1.0   APPLY        COMPLETE     09/16/14     13:49:36    
                 6.1.8.16   COMMIT       COMPLETE     09/16/14     13:59:18    
                 6.1.8.16   APPLY        COMPLETE     09/16/14     13:55:32    
                 6.1.9.30   COMMIT       COMPLETE     07/02/15     16:36:49    
                 6.1.9.30   APPLY        COMPLETE     07/02/15     16:33:23    
                 6.1.9.45   COMMIT       COMPLETE     09/04/15     15:45:19    
                 6.1.9.45   APPLY        COMPLETE     09/04/15     15:45:10    
                6.1.9.101   APPLY        COMPLETE     09/14/17     16:44:45
```

Or else I need only last line of above output.

Comment: What's the point of the last update *date*?  Updating a 6-year-old kernel to a 5-year-old kernel last week doesn't mean the kernel is current.  Either the *version* is up-to-date or it's not - *when* it was updated is irrelevant.

Comment: @AndrewHenle not necessarily irrelevant.  if the machine or an application running on it is crashing in obscure circumstances and your logs show it only started happening **after** the kernel was upgraded from an ancient version to a slightly less ancient version, that's a pretty good indicator that it might be the kernel at fault.  If the crash was happening before and after the kernel upgrade, it's unlikely to be implicated.

Comment: @cas True, but if that's the reason for this question, it's on the way towards being an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) then, no?  Hence the reasone I asked *What's the point of the last update date?*

Comment: @AndrewHenle My point was that it doesn't matter WHY the OP wants this information, it's not up to us here to judge whether it's useful or not.

Answer (score 2):

For the AIX part, instead of hard-coding the `bos.adt.base` fileset, and instead of asking for *all* of the updates -- applies and commits -- but instead just the commits, I would ask for the history of the fileset that owns the /unix symlink (which points to the kernel):

```
lslpp -q -c -h -Or $(lslpp -q -c -w /unix | cut -d: -f2) | tail -1 | cut -d: -f7-8
```

In pieces, that's:

- -q  -- don't print column headings
- -c  -- print output colon-delimited (easier to parse)
- -h  -- fileset history
- -w  -- which fileset owns the given file
- -Or -- only need one set; `r`oot or `u`sr works here

From the inside out, we get the fileset name from `lslpp ... -w` and then ask for the history of that fileset; that's then piped to `tail` to get the last line (assumed to be the most recent), and then to `cut` to pull out the date and time fields.

For the Solaris part, perhaps the most recently applied patch to the kernel would suffice?

```
nawk -F: '/^PATCH_INFO/ { sub(" From", ""); print $2":"$3":"$4; }' \
  /var/sadm/pkg/SUNWckr/pkginfo | 
    sort -k6n | tail -1
```

Answer (score 1):

On Solaris, you'll see the kernel patch installed by running:
`uname -v | awk -F_ '{print $2}'`

If you then run:
`ls -lat /var/sadm/patch |grep <patch>`

You'll see the timestamp of when it was installed.  There will also be logs in that directory if you want further information.

Comment: `/var/sadm/patch` will only be present on Solaris 10 and earlier, on Solaris 11.x you'll need to use `pkg info system/kernel` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last line of any output by piping it to `tail -1`.  Try this:

```
lslpp -ha bos.adt.base | sed -n '/COMPLETE/ s/^k.*\s\s//p' | tail -1
```

I've also folded the `grep` command into the `sed` command - it wasn't doing anything that `sed` can't do itself.

NOTE: I'm not familiar with the AIX `lslpp` command, so I'm just assuming it's the right tool to use for this job, and that you've used the most appropriate options with it.  It may be worth reading the man page to see if there are better ways of using it to get what you want.

Comment: btw, too bad about the weird MM/DD/YY date format.  if it was ISO-8601 standard YYYY-MM-DD, it could easily be sorted.